# Python: Usando label en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

para un programa quiero colocar dos label "Question" y "Answer" al lado de dos cuadro de texto. Como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que con el siguiente código:

```
from tkinter import *

#Creando una ventanta principal
window=Tk()
window.geometry("500x300+100+100")
window.title("Question Editor")

#Creando un campo de texto para question
Entryquestion=StringVar()
Entryquestion.set("")
txtquestion=Entry(window,textvariable=Entryquestion).place(x=50,y=140)

#Creando un campo de texto para answer
Entryanswer=StringVar()
Entryanswer.set("")
txtquestion=Entry(window,textvariable=Entryanswer).place(x=50,y=170)
#Creando un label para el campo de texto "question"
var1 = StringVar()
label = Label( window, textvariable=var1, padx=10 )

var1.set("Question")
label.pack()

#Creando un label para el campo de texto "answer"
var2 = StringVar()
label = Label( window, textvariable=var2, padx=10 )
var2.set("Answer")
label.pack()

#Creando un botón para guardar pregunta y respuesta
btnSave=Button(window,text="Save question and answer",command=Entryquestion,font=("Agency FB",14)).place(x=130,y=200)
```

Me da el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener la configuración visual de la primera imagen que he mostrado?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando `place` para posicionar tus entries y el botón pero usas `pack` para los labels. `pack` por defecto posiciona los widgets alineados en columna de arriba a abajo.

Hay varias formas de hacer esto pero puedes seguir la máxima de 'divide y vencerás'. Para alinear los label y los entries se suele usar un [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm). Puedes usar un contenedor (un `Frame`) que contendrá lo dos `Entry` y los dos `Label` y luego posicionas el `Frame` adecuadamente.

Dos observaciones:

- No debes usar para importar el modelo:

  ```
  from tkinter import *
  ```

  Puede que en tu programa no tengas grandes problemas al ser pequeño pero te aseguro que te puedes encontrar con sorpresas desagradables al usar librerias extensas y complejas. En su lugar usa algo como:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk
  ```
- No te aconsejo usar en la misma línea la instancia del widget y su posicionamiento usando `grid`, `place` o `pack`, si haces:

  ```
  btnSave=tk.Button(window,text="Save",command=Entryquestion,).place(x=130,y=200)
  ```

  Ahora `btnSave` no es una instancia de `tkinter.Button` sino que es `None`, el retorno del método `place`. Si ahora quisieras usar la variable `btnSave` para cambiar, por ejemplo, el texto del botón no podrias. En su lugar, separa las líneas:

  ```
  btnSave=tk.Button(window,text="Save",command=Entryquestion,)
  btnSave.place(x=130,y=200)
  ```

El código podría ser algo así:

```
import tkinter as tk

def Entryquestion():
    pass

#Creando una ventanta principal
window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x300+100+100")
window.title("Question Editor")

#Creamos un frame como contenedor
frame = tk.Frame(window)

#Creando un campo de texto para question
entryQuestion=tk.StringVar()
entryQuestion.set("")
txtQuestion=tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=entryQuestion)
txtQuestion.grid(row=0, column=1)

#Creando un campo de texto para answer
entryAnswer=tk.StringVar()
entryAnswer.set("")
txtAnswer=tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=entryAnswer)
txtAnswer.grid(row=2, column=1)

#Creando un label para el campo de texto "question"
labelQuestion = tk.Label(frame, text="Question", padx=10 )
labelQuestion.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

#Creando un label para el campo de texto "answer"
labelAnswer = tk.Label(frame, text="Answer", padx=10 )
labelAnswer.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

#Definimos un tamaño mínimo de la fila central delgrid para que quede un espacio entre cada entry y posicionamos el frame
frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, minsize=10)
frame.place(x=0,y=140)

#Creando un botón para guardar pregunta y respuesta
btnSave=tk.Button(window,text="Save question and answer",command=Entryquestion,font=("Agency FB",14))
btnSave.place(x=130,y=200)

#Iniciamos el mailoop
window.mainloop()
```

Obtenemos algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]